# Spamassassin && Exim: redirect spam emails

Tags: spam, exim, spamassassin

I want to redirect all email, being marked as ***SPAM*** to special mailbox.

Works with **Exim4**, **SpamAssassin Server** version 3.3.1 on **CentOS** 6.5.

Rules from Exim in `acl_check_data` block:

```
  warn  message = X-Redirect-To: spam@mail.com
    hosts    = !+relay_from_hosts
    spam    = nobody

  warn  spam    = nobody:true
    hosts    = !+relay_from_hosts
    message    = X-Spam-Level: $spam_bar

  warn  spam    = nobody:true
    hosts    = !+relay_from_hosts
    condition = ${if >{$spam_score_int}{29}{1}{0}}
    message = X-Spam-Status: $spam_report

  deny  message    = Message scored $spam_score spam points
    spam        = nobody:true
    condition    = ${if >{$spam_score_int}{100}{yes}{no}}
```

Next, in `routers`:

```
spam_redirect:
    driver = redirect
    condition = ${if def:h_X-Redirect-To: {1}{0}}
    headers_add = X-Original-Recipient: $local_part@$domain
    data = $h_X-Redirect-To:
    headers_remove = X-Redirect-To
    redirect_router = dovecot_user
```

And as result - spam really blocked:

> 2014-07-14 15:27:45 1X6fLq-0007x4-FI H=([117.208.154.131])
>   [117.208.154.131] I=[77.***.***.20]:25
>   F= rejected after DATA: Message scored
>   10.8 spam points

But I don't receive this email in my box *spam@mail.com*.

Comment: Message was rejected so delivery hasn't been performed.